# Unit test a web service's call to another web service in Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, rest, unit-testing, mocking

I'm developing 2 REST web services in Jersey, let's call it web service A and B. In fact, when client sends a request to A, A then sends a request to B to get the data in JSON, processes them and sends the response to client. 
Now I've done the unit testing for web service B:

```
public class BTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        return new MockApplicationConfig();
    }

    @Test
    public void testBService() {
        Form form = new Form();
        form.add("name", "JohnDoe");

        String response = this.target("/B/list").request().post(Entity.form(form), String.class)
                .toString();
        Output output = new Gson().fromJson(response, Output.class);
        ....
    }
```

I don't know how to unit test web service A. I use Maven to build the project so I don't want to manually set up  B's server and run unit test on A (to call B service). Is there any way so that I could mock B web service for A to call it?

Comment: @nLee you meant using Jetty to setup B, mock it and use A to call B?

Comment: Yes, in fact you could use Jetty to mock both services separately. Jetty is quite lightweight and doesnt take more than a few lines of code to set up